# How to override woocommerce product-image template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, path

I want to use my own custom template file *(with a custom name)* for product image and gallery thumbnails, so need to override the default Woocommerce product-image template by using this:

```
add_filter( 'wc_get_template', 'modify_product_gallery_template', 10, 5 );
function modify_product_gallery_template( $located, $template_name, $args, $template_path, $default_path ) {
    if ( 'single-product/product-image.php' == $template_name ) {
        $located = '... my-gallery.include.php';
    }

    return $located;
}
```

But no success yet. Is there any other way for doing this?

Answer (score 3):

It's **a problem of path** that has to be the absolute server path using [`get_theme_file_path()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_file_path/) for example.

Assuming that your custom template file is named `my-gallery.include.php` and if:

**1) it's located in your active theme's root directory** you will use:

```
$located = get_theme_file_path('/my-gallery.include.php');
```

So in your code:

```
add_filter( 'wc_get_template', 'modify_product_gallery_template', 10, 5 );
function modify_product_gallery_template( $located, $template_name, $args, $template_path, $default_path ) {
    if ( 'single-product/product-image.php' == $template_name ) {
        $located = get_theme_file_path('/my-gallery.include.php');
    }
    return $located;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

**2) it's located inside a your active theme on a `woocommerce` subfolder**, you will use:

```
$located = get_theme_file_path('/woocommerce/my-gallery.include.php');
```

**3) If you want to [override the template via your active theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)**, just copy the file from the woocommerce plugin to: `woocommerce/single-product/product-image.php`…

Now you can open edit the copied template and make changes without your actual code and the changes will appear once saved.

Comment: Nice - didn't know about using `get_theme_file_path` instead of `get_stylesheet_directory / get_stylesheet_directory_uri`

Comment: @Stender First, `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` works only for the child theme and don't gives the server path, but an URL, which doesn't work for templates location in this hook.

Answer (score 1):

To override any woocommerce template you don't need to write any code. You can do is simply creating that file inside your active theme. For Example in your case you want to overwrite 'product-image.php' which is located inside

> wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-image.php

So for that what you can do, you can just create that template inside your path and for that you need to create the path to the template inside the theme. Like in your case create the path to the template i.e :

> woocommerce -> templates -> single-product -> product-image.php

When woocommerce runs it will take the template from the theme if available else from the plugin.

Hope this make sense.

Comment: thanks @Malaya but in my case i need to override in my plugin not in theme. Which hook need to use for this purpose ?

Comment: Ok. So you can use following code instead:  

`function myplugin_woocommerce_locate_template( $template, $template_name, $template_path ) {
  global $woocommerce;
   if ( 'single-product/product-image.php' == $template_name ) {
        $located = '... my-gallery.include.php';
    }

    return $located;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_locate_template',  myplugin_woocommerce_locate_template', 10, 3);`

Answer (score 0):

You can override woocommerce product-image template

```
project/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-image.php
```

Create below folder structure and copy above page and do modification as per your requirement

```
project/wp-content/themes/yourtheme/woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-image.php
```